# What the equivalent of BYTE array (BYTE[]) in Delphi with null termination a integer?

Tags: arrays, sockets, delphi, delphi-10-seattle

I'm stuck in this trouble where the compiler says:

> Incompatible types: 'AnsiChar' and 'Integer'

to the last element of `AnsiChar` array, that is a integer that is a null termination. How fix it?

C++ code:

```
static const BYTE  myarray[] = { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 0 };
SOCKET s;

// Usage example:
if(Send(s, (char *) myarray, sizeof(myarray), 0) <= 0)
      return;
```

My attempt in Delphi:

```
var
  MyArray: array [0 .. MAX_PATH] of AnsiChar = ( 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 0 );
  S: TSocket;

// Usage example:
send(S, MyArray, Length(MyArray), 0);
```

Comment: @Rudy It's not the best dupe. I reopened it. Please post your answer. Best explain ordinal char literals too. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can *almost* define it the way you did:

```delphi
var
  MyArray: array[0..MAX_PATH] of AnsiChar = ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', #0);
```

But then you get an error complaining about the number of elements, so you would have to add some 250 extra zeroes to complete it:

```delphi
// Possible, but not necessary, see below 
var
  MyArray: array[0..MAX_PATH] of AnsiChar = 
    ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 
     'I',  #0,  #0,  #0,  #0, ....
                ...
                ...
                ...            #0,  #0,  #0);
```

This can be done much simpler, however:

```delphi
var
  MyArray: array[0..MAX_PATH] of AnsiChar = 'ABCDEFGHI';
```

This special syntax should work in most versions of Delphi and not get a compiler error.

For the length during a *send()*, you'll have to use *StrLen()*, not *Length()*:

```delphi
send(S, MyArray, StrLen(MyArray) + 1, 0);
```

Alternatively, you can do this:

```delphi
var
  Stg: AnsiString;
begin
  Stg := 'ABCDEFGHI';
  // Second parameter is untyped const, so use ^
  send(S, PAnsiChar(Stg)^, Length(Stg) + 1, 0);
```

---

FWIW, `#0` is the character with *ordinal value 0*. Alternatives are:

```
Chr(0)
#0
^@ (meaning Control+@; ^A = #1 = Chr(1), ^M = #13, etc.)
```

Each of the above has the same meaning.

Comment: Isn't Length the length of the array? And so not equal to the sizeof from the C++ code.

Comment: @David: `Length(MyArray)` is `MAX_PATH+1`. Just checked that. Updated my answer.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis, **`E2036 Variable required`** here: `PAnsiChar(Stg)` on alternative solution of your answer. How fix?

Comment: I did not know that the second parameter of send is a var parameter (probably an untyped var parameter?). In that case, you'll have to pass `PAnsiChar(Stg)^` (note the added `^`).

Comment: Not untyped var, but untyped const. Must admit I never used Winapi.WSocket(2).send() before.

Comment: Why is `MAX_PATH` being used at all? In the original C++ code, the array length is only 10 chars max, not the 261 chars that the Delphi code is forcing. Fix the array as `MyArray: array [0 .. 9] of AnsiChar`, then `Sizeof()` can be used in the Delphi code instead of using `Length()` or `StrLen()+1`

Comment: @Remy: assuming the buffer may be re-used to receive it could be useful to have a larger one. Why MAX_PATH, I don't know. But counting the bytes is not necessary, IMO. I would actually use the string, but otherwise, i would use an overdimensional buffer too and simply use StrLen.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis but the original C++ code wasn't using a reusable buffer, and the OP was simply asking for a translation of the C++ code to Delphi.

Comment: @Remy: I know. The OP also introduced the MAX_PATH constant. As I said, I would use the `PAnsiChar(AnsiString)^` variety, exactly because a reusable buffer doesn't seem to be required.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `#0` to represent numeric 0 as an `AnsiChar`.  But, the C++ code is assigning `char` values to a `BYTE` array, and you can't implicitly assign an `AnsiChar` to a `Byte` in Delphi, you need a type-cast.

A literal translation of the C++ code to Delphi would look more like this:

```pascal
const
  myarray[0..9] of Byte = (Ord('A'), Ord('B'), Ord('C'), Ord('D'), Ord('E'), Ord('F'), Ord('G'), Ord('H'), Ord('I'), 0);
  // alternatively:
  // myarray[0..9] of AnsiChar = ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', #0);

var
  s: SOCKET;
begin
  ...
  // Usage example:
  if (send(s, myarray, SizeOf(myarray), 0) <= 0) then
    Exit;
  ...
end;
```

Comment: based on my last question about [`send()` a **PByte** type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55699624/winsock-how-send-a-pbyte-type), here we also can make: `send(s, myarray^, SizeOf(myarray), 0)`? PS: `myarray^` or simply `myarray`? See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55699624/winsock-how-send-a-pbyte-type?noredirect=1#comment98084638_55699624).

Comment: @BrowJr you can't use `^` to dereference a fixed array in Delphi, only a pointer, and there is no need to use a pointer in this example, in fact there is no need to dereference the fixed array at all