# WinSock: How send() a PByte type?

Tags: sockets, delphi, winsock, delphi-10-seattle

Firstly, i want know if the `PByte` type is equivalent to a `BYTE*`(byte pointer) in C++. In negative case, what's could be on Delphi that more near to `BYTE*` of C++?

Well, suppose that i'm right about that `PByte` is `BYTE*` (C++), then based on following C++ code, how `send()` this data type (`PByte`) correctly using native WinSock?

See:

C++:

```
SOCKET sock;
BITMAPINFO bmpInfo;
BYTE *bytes = NULL;
BYTE *temp_bytes = NULL;
DWORD workSpaceSize, fragmntWorkSpaceSize, size;

 RtlGetCompressionWorkSpaceSize(COMPRESSION_FORMAT_LZNT1, &workSpaceSize, &fragmntWorkSpaceSize);

 bytes = (BYTE *) Alloc(bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biSizeImage);
 temp_bytes = (BYTE *) Alloc(bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biSizeImage);
 BYTE *memory = (BYTE *) Alloc(workSpaceSize);

 RtlCompressBuffer(COMPRESSION_FORMAT_LZNT1, 
             bytes, 
             bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biSizeImage, 
             temp_bytes, 
             bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biSizeImage, 
             2048,
             &size,
             memory);

 free(bytes);
 free(memory);

 if(Send(sock, (char *) temp_bytes, size, 0) <= 0) return;

 free(temp_bytes);
```

Delphi:

```
var
 Sock: TSocket;
 bmpInfo: TBitMapInfo;
 bytes: PByte = nil;
 temp_bytes: PByte = nil;
 memory: PByte;
 workSpaceSize, fragmntWorkSpaceSize, Size: Cardinal;

 //...

RtlGetCompressionWorkSpaceSize(COMPRESSION_FORMAT_LZNT1, @workSpaceSize, @fragmntWorkSpaceSize);

bytes := AllocMem(bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biSizeImage);
temp_bytes := AllocMem(bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biSizeImage);
memory := AllocMem(workSpaceSize);

RtlCompressBuffer(COMPRESSION_FORMAT_LZNT1, bytes, bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biSizeImage, 
                  temp_bytes, bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biSizeImage, 2048, @Size, memory);

FreeMem(bytes);
FreeMem(memory);

if send(Sock, temp_bytes^, Size, 0) <= 0 then Exit;

FreeMem(temp_bytes);
```

- [Reference](https://0x00sec.org/t/compress-and-decompress-buffer-using-c-language/7401/3) to `RtlGetCompressionWorkSpaceSize()` and `RtlCompressBuffer()` functions in **C++**.
- [Reference](http://www.delphibasics.info/home/delphibasicssnippets/untntcompressbyerazerz) to `RtlGetCompressionWorkSpaceSize()` and `RtlCompressBuffer()` functions in **Delphi**.

Comment: Yes, `PByte` is equal to `BYTE*` and your usage looks right at the first glance. I just doubt - where is `temp_bytes` allocated??

Comment: @MBo, i edited the both codes. I'm sending `temp_bytes` correctly on Delphi code?

Comment: Yes (concerning dereferencing pointer for using as untyped var argument). Note that `temp_bytes` freeing is after possible Exit

Comment: @MBo, "*`(concerning dereferencing pointer for using as untyped var argument)`*". Then this could be simply `send(Sock, temp_bytes, Size, 0)`?

Comment: No, your variant with `temp_bytes^` is correct - I just emphasized this moment

Comment: `send(Sock, temp_bytes, Size, 0)` is wrong. The code in your question is correct.

Comment: Anyway, I can't quite see a question. What are you asking?

Comment: Quite simple: PByte is sent the same way as PAnsiChar. So `temp_bytes^` is correct.

Comment: FWIW, the discrepancy and confusion occurs because the original code uses an (untyped) pointer, while Delphi uses a Delphi-specific construct, an [untyped const parameter](http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-pointers.html#untypedparams) (link to an article of mine). ISTM they should simply have used Pointer and that would have removed all confusion. Not everyone groks untyped parameters: reference parameters but without a type.